# Evaluation of an expression for different functions

Tags: evaluation, replacement

Suppose I have function

```
a[t_]:=f'[t]/f[t].
```

The actual expression is more complicated but the idea is the same.

I want to evaluate `a[t]` for `f=f_1` and `f=f_2` and plot the results.

I tried

```
a[t] /. {f[t]->f_1[t]}
```

but it didn't help.

How can it be done?

Best,
Furkan

Comment: `a[t_,f_]:=f'[t]; a[t,f_1]`

Comment: @Coolwater it worked! Thanks a lot (=

Comment: @FurkanSemihDündar, remember that in _Mathematica_, `f_1` means a pattern, that we refer to as `f`, that matches any expression with `Head` 1.